# WMI - Getting Last Logon Time of PC

Tags: powershell, active-directory, wmi

So I'm struggling to write this script that's supposed to get the last time a client was used, Serial Number and Name of the PC. I've already asked a question today regarding a problem I encountered with Get-WmiObject but a very helpful commenter told me that there are probably better ways to solve this problem.

So my main problem in the last wuestion was the amount of "RPC is unavailable" error messages and the sheer amount of time the command needs for every client.

```
$Computers = Get-ADComputer -filter * | 
    Select-Object -first 1 | 
    Select-Object -expandProperty Name

write-host $computers
foreach ($name in $computers) {
    Get-WmiObject -Class win32_process -ComputerName $name | Where-Object {
        $_.name -Match "explorer*"
    } | ForEach-Object {
        @{ PC = $name; User = $_.getowner().user}
    } | Out-GridView
}
```

I've also tried

```
Get-ChildItem "\\$computers\c$\Users" 
| Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending 
| Select-Object Name, LastWriteTime -first 1 | Out-GridView
```

which sometimes works but not always.

I've also tried a command using the EventLog whcih resulted in a pretty inaccurate last logon date.

Thanks for helping, and please bear with me I'm still pretty new to this

Comment: Not sure how checking the owner of the Explorer process gives you what you want.  It would only work if someone is actually logged on and doesn't tell you when they did that.  Did you try enabling [logon auditing](https://www.howtogeek.com/124313/how-to-see-who-logged-into-a-computer-and-when/)?

Comment: How would I check the date in powershell?

Comment: The date that the owner of the Explorer process logged on?  I guess the `CreationDate` is probably what you need, though, as I said, this is only valid if Explorer is running.  One way to get that is:  `(Get-CimInstance -Query "SELECT CreationDate FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name LIKE '%explorer%'").CreationDate`.  Note that `Get-CimInstance` is a better choice here as it automatically converts the date for you, but with `Get-WmiObject`, you'd need to do that yourself.

Comment: Why the %explorer% part? Just to clarify I need the last logon date. Doesnt matter who. And wold this work even if the computer is turned off?

Comment: I don't believe logon date/time is stored anywhere unless you enable the logging I mentioned before.  Everything else is a proxy for that.  Here, I was suggesting a change to your original code sample to show the time that the Explorer process was created, which you can take as a rough indicator of when the user logged on because Explorer is created almost immediately after logon.

Comment: I enabled the audit logon but I thought that its only saved on the local client and there is no way to access it if the client is turned off.

Comment: _" there is no way to access it if the client is turned off"_ That's to be expected.  You're examples above connect to the target system and query stuff there. So, what you really want is a central place where logons are logged and accessible even if the system is off.  A couple of options you could look at yourself are [event log forwarding](https://www.petri.com/configure-event-log-forwarding-windows-server-2012-r2) or setting a logon script for users that logs to a database on your network. [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) might be a better place for this question.

Comment: Thanks a lot i think i'll write a logon script. But my boss told me this would be enough for right now.

Comment: If you're in a Windows domain environment, active directory maintains some login info you can query from the machine account objects. The granularity and accuracy of this info varies, especially if you're querying across multiple domains. For what it's worth, I've solved this on a network of 1000 workstations with a startup script that wrote data to a fileshare.